# Film where a man's head gets squashed

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a film in which a black man's head is squashed by a man with some sort of super powers, the man puts his thumbs on the black man's forhead and pushes until his head is distorted, although he does not die. I think it is set in some sort of space station, with white walls.

I watched the film around 3 years ago, English, sci fi and space themed, I have a feeling that the space station was some sort of universal bank (for storing currency)

Comment: Is there any more you can tell us? What language was it in? When did you watch it? Was it older or newer? Every additional detail helps.

Comment: I watched the film around 3 years ago, English, sci fi and space themed, I have a feeling that the space station was some sort of universal bank (for storing currency)

Comment: Are you sure it was a man that squished his head? There was an alien on a bank planet that used some kind of psychic power to cause people's heads to cave in, including a black man, in the Doctor Who episode ["Time Heist"](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Heist_(TV_story)) from September 2014, you can see a clip just after 1:30 in some guy's youtube review [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExTEQT3Xtzo&t=1m30s).

Comment: Yeah this sounds a lot like Time Heist

Comment: Thanks guys, it was time heist after all, sorry for the confusion, I just couldn't remember it properly!

Comment: @Hypnosifl _Doctor Who_'s "Time Heist" was confirmed by OP, kick that one out of Unanswered tab :)

Comment: @Hypnosifl I think you should put it as an answer, so this gets cleared from the Unanswered